# BASH: Print Nth Letter From Beginning

Tags: bash, file, cut

I want to read all file and print Nth letter (just letter) from beginning in all lines.

I read file like this:

> while read line
>
> do
>
> echo $line >> text.txt
>
> done < input.txt

Then i do this:

> cut -c3 text.txt

But i realize that it doesn't working as i want in these inputs:

> He llo

or

> re+set

I want to get 'l' for first input and 's' for second input.

But this code found ' ' for first input and '+' for second input

And anubhava wrote this code:

> awk -v n=3 '{gsub(/ +/, ""); print substr($0, n, 1)}' file

It was working for Nth letter except space

But now i want print Nth letter (just letter)

What should i do ?

Comment: Can you provide some sample input and output?

Comment: Do you want it to skip the line if the 3rd character is space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this awk:

```
awk -v n=3 '{gsub(/ +/, ""); print substr($0, n, 1)}' file
```

**Testing:**

```
s='re set'
awk -v n=3 '{gsub(/ +/, ""); print substr($0, n, 1)}' <<< "$s"
s

s='He llo'
awk -v n=3 '{gsub(/ +/, ""); print substr($0, n, 1)}' <<< "$s"
l

s='1 2 345'
awk -v n=3 '{gsub(/ +/, ""); print substr($0, n, 1)}' <<< "$s"
3
```

Comment: My problem changed. It was working for other problem. Can you look this problem too?

Comment: If you remove `gsub(/ +/, "");` call it will just print `nth` letter in the input.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So is gsub() help remove space ?

Comment: Yes `gsub` is for removing spaces only.

Comment: Also is there a easier way to do this with 'cut' command? Because Im trying to learn cut command.

Comment: No `cut` cannot be used for replacement, that only be used for getting a column(s) and/or field. So you can do `cut -c 3 file` in cut but no substitution.